# Proper rounding when converting between digitized values and floating point

Tags: quantization, conversion

I have some very large files that are unsigned 8 bit (0 to 255), real valued.  I need to do some simple tuning and decimation.  In the past, when I've dealt with low bit rate samples, I've run into issues with artifacts.  I want to make sure I get the rounding correct.

The data will be processed in Matlab using all native double precision.  The first question is should I subtract 127.5 or 128 when converting, or does it depend?

To keep things simple, I'm not doing anything fancy with the filter gain or multiple passes to make sure I don't clip.  Instead I'll notify the user if there was a problem.  The output also needs to be the same format, so I can't use any additional effective bits gained by decimation.  The next thing I'm unsure about is do I round 255.3 down to 255 or do I consider this an overflow condition?

EDIT

I thought I could just process the data with the offset in there doing something like this at the output.

```
y = y * scale + (1-scale)/2*255
```

The trouble is the tuning operation may filter out the offset before I correct for it.  So instead, I decided the simplest thing to do is subtract 127.5 and add it back in at the end.  Then round as I described above.

I'm not sure how the different methods of adjusting for the offset and scaling effect the resultant artifacts, but as arnfinn said there is probably nothing I can do about in any case (unless I'm willing to use dither).

EDIT 2

This is actually more along the lines of what I was thinking would be an issue.  In the distant past I have experienced this exact problem with requantization.  Certain combinations of quantization parameters can really mess up quality (worse artifacts).  My situation is a little different because I'm processing the data before requantization.  But I believe it can still be an issue.

[A requantization algorithm for the transcoding of JPEG images](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0923596505000494)

Signal Processing: Image Communication.
Volume 21, Issue 1, January 2006, Pages 13–21.
Jae Won Moona, Jong Seok Leeb, Nam Ik Cho.

Comment: I think you should subtract 127.5... but why would you ever have 255.3?

Comment: sometimes there is DC from the ADC that gets into these old 8-bit unsigned .wav files.  i think that `0x80` should be subtracted and you have a maximum negative that is slightly bigger in amplitude than the maximum positive.  everything else is just scaling. i'm also wondering where you're getting "255.3" out of an unsigned 8-bit value?  converting **to** 8-bit unsigned, you should scale it to a maximum of $\pm$127, round-to-nearest, and add `0x80`.

Comment: or, for better audio quality, dither an/or noise-shape the conversion back to 8-bit.

Comment: Don't assume audio.  I am familiar with dithering, but I'm not sure it makes sense here.  Maybe I'm just worrying about a non issue with the artifacts.  We have one vote now for 127.5 and one for 128.  Does anyone have a more detailed answer?  The reason for potentially having values above 255 is that I won't know the proper scale value ahead of time.  That only works if you can load the entire file into memory all at once.

Comment: Why do you want to shift the data? Is it to avoid initial transients? Is it from a constant mean process? If you want to remove any transient due to a DC component, you probably want to remove the mean value...

Comment: No, it's simply so I can tune, filter, and decimate.  Can I just leave the offset in while processing since I ultimately need to shift it back anyway?

Comment: in those 8-bit `.wav` files, `0x80` means zero.  the format is called **offset binary** where `0x00` is the most negative value and `0xFF` means the most positive value.  this is **not** the case for 16-bit or `.wav` files of wider word width.  if these are not `.wav` files but just a binary file of 8-bit samples, then you need to consult whoever created the original file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you don't have to worry too much about so-called 'transparency' (ability to represent accurately the integer value as a floating point value) unless you do normalization. See the `libsndfile` [FAQ](http://www.mega-nerd.com/libsndfile/FAQ.html#Q010).

As quantization is a lossy operation (many-to-one, or surjective, mapping) you will always have artifacts when re-quantizing from floating point to integer values. The standard method for de-correlating the quantization error is to use [dither](http://www.ece.rochester.edu/courses/ECE472/resources/Papers/Lipshitz_1992.pdf). For small word lengths, such as 8 bit, the classic solution of adding noise with a triangular distribution might cause the dither noise to be unaccptably high, so you might have to look around for some semi-optimal (in terms of quantization error moments) dithering method that suits your application better. Or just re-quantize and accept the artifacts, they might be small, depending on your data and what you are planning to do with it.

Comment: My question was maybe a little ill-conceived.  I accepted your answer for providing useful information regarding the topic.